# Help with report - optimize report filter logic

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, filters

Need to amend a report from my predecessor that will show all the tasks which **are created by a user but not assigned to them** (and vice versa) e.g. Created by MR A and Assigned to MR B - NEVER Created by MR A and Assigned to MR A or Created by MR B and Assigned to MR B

Is there a simple way to do this without typing the user's names in the 'assigned to equals' and 'created by not equals to' filters on the report? (there are quite a few users and is also hard to manage if adding/ removing manually!)

N.B. All users do belong the same role for this report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can work

- Add a new checkbox formula field on Task, called `Is_Assigned_to_Creator__c`
- Formula is `CreatedById = OwnerId`
- Change the report filter to look for `Is_Assigned_to_Creator__c = false` to find all Tasks assigned to someone other than the creator. Use additional filters for specific usernames

Comment: Perfect! Works 100%

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is not possible yet to compare a field to another field in Salesforce reports. But you can upvote the following idea of improvement:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0